# How to Update signin User in Microsoft graph Api

Tags: node.js, express, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to update sign-in user displayName in Azure Active Directory using Microsoft graph SDK in node js.
I Have tried something like this:-

Index.js

```
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const app: Express = express();
const port = +process.env.PORT! | 3000;

// Routes
import userRoutes from './Routes/User';

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send('Express + TypeScript Server');
});

// config routes
app.use('/user', userRoutes);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`⚡️[server]: Server is running at https://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

AuthProvider.ts

```
import { TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/authProviders/azureTokenCredentials';
import {
  AuthorizationCodeCredential,
  ClientSecretCredential,
} from '@azure/identity';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

// const credential = new AuthorizationCodeCredential(
//   process.env.TENANT_ID!,
//   process.env.CLIENT_ID!,
//   process.env.AUTH_CODE!,
//   process.env.REDIRECT_URL!
// );

const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(
  process.env.TENANT_ID!,
  process.env.CLIENT_ID!,
  process.env.CLIENT_SECRET!
);

const authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider(credential, {
  scopes: ['User.Read'],
});

export default authProvider;
```

I have used this auth provider code. I don't know which class is best for this case.

Routes.TS

```
userRoutes.get(
  '/update',
  Auth,
  async (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {
    try {
      // bearer token
      const accessToken = request.body.token;
      const user = {
        displayName: 'Sabban',
      };

      const client = Client.initWithMiddleware({
        debugLogging: true,
        authProvider,
      });

      const data = await client
        .api('/me')
        .headers({
          Authorization: accessToken,
        })
        .update(user);

      response.json({ err: 0, message: 'Update User', data });
    } catch (error: any) {
      response.json({ err: 1, message: error.message, error });
    }
  }
);
```

I have hard-coded the value as of now to check whether API is working or not but getting errors.

> invalid_scope: 1002012 - [2022-08-04 06:41:36Z]: AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope User.Read openid profile offline_access is not valid.

If I have implemented it wrong then kidly suggest the way.

I have read enough documents but did not get anything any help would be appreciable.

Comment: One thing that I notice is that you are trying to run the update on /me, which doesn't seem to be supported according to docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request. You'll need to use the `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}` URL specified in docs I think.

Comment: But if you see graph explorer there is a endpoint for patch me .https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Ah, sorry. I now see that you only have User.Read scope. You need the "User.ReadWrite" scope to modify users.

Comment: Hi @Mohmad sabban, is your issue resolved, as mentioned above you need 'User.ReadWrite.All' application permission, please check document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Answer (score 0):

> AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope User.Read openid profile offline_access is not valid.

***The error occurs due to incorrect scope Api permission or not given admin to grant consent in Azure active directory.***

I tried in my environment with similar scopes which got same error:

[image]

Please make sure with permission that admin has to be **granted consent.**

***Go Azure active directory -> Api permissions -> Grant admin consent***

[image]

The **Microsoft Graph scope** to work, it should be**`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`** scope

When I tried with above scope I got successfully access token:

[image]

Reference:
[The Client credential provider example does not work · Issue #14323 · microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs (github.com)](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/14323)